# What is a decent ORM to use in an ionic framework based project

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Currently, I am learning ionic framework and planning to develop a mobile application using ionic framework with database operation. ORM helps to operator database operation faster. Could you please suggest any ORM that supports ionic framework

Comment: I've personally found query builders to be more flexible than traditional ORM since you don't need to tell the library your schema. Also, it makes constructing complex queries easy. Check out knex.js. I've used it in a few projects and have been happy with it.

Comment: This looks like nice: [https://github.com/lykmapipo/ngData](https://github.com/lykmapipo/ngData), probably I will use in a new project.